# Something similar to CSS in Microsoft Visio 2010?

Tags: css, web, visio, mockups

I'm looking for something similar to CSS in MS Visio 2010 for UI mockups for a website.  I'm currently using the Visio Wire Frame to create the individual web app page mockup screens.  However, it's turning into a massive amount of different screens with no way of tying commonalities between the screens together.  I'd like to be able to snap-in different parts of the screen that applies across all of the screens.  For instance, the nav bar would apply to all screens.  It would be helpful if I could just snap that in or import it to every screen so that when I need to modify it, it automatically applies across all the screens I've created.  In other words, something similar to Cascading Style Sheets.  If anybody knows if there is a way to do this in MS Visio 2010, I would appreciate some steps in how to pull this off.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at 'Background' pages a layers.  Any page can be set as a background page (select 'Page Setup' from the page tab context menu) onto which you can drop shapes.  You can then set other 'foreground' pages to use a particular background page and this will give you the ASP.NET master page style you're describing.  Have a look at this post for more info on background pages:

[Applying a background or border design in Visio - Visio Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visio/archive/2009/09/18/applying-a-background-or-border-design-in-visio-2010.aspx)

You might also find layers useful.  Shapes can be assigned to different layers and a layer's visibility can be toggled on and off as required.  Bear in mind that Visio layers don't work in quite the same way as Photoshop layers.  The Visio system of layers is more akin to tagging.  This means that a shape can belong to multiple layers.  Something to think about regarding visibility.  For more info on layers:

[Assigning shapes and masters to layer - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa217451%28office.10%29.aspx)

[Working with layers - Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/CH001040870.aspx)

Comment: I appreciate the advice.  Very helpful, indeed.  I have one other problem that I'm hoping you might have an answer for.  Apparently, Visio doesn't allow you to resize background layers beyond 1 page.  Do you know a way around this?  I'm trying to create a background that spans 2-3 pages to simulate a web page.  I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Visio does allow you to place shapes outside of the bounds of the page (although I haven't come across a good use case for this before).  
Just to be clear, layers are an abstract concept so you can stretch the shapes assigned to a layer but not the layer itself.  
As far as spanning multiple pages, you'll need to match the size of your background pages to the foreground pages they're paired with.

Comment: Although this means that you might have to multiple background pages (of varying sizes) you can create a master grouped shape, to hold your background shapes, that will resize itself to the (background) page on which it's dropped.  
For example the Width cell of you shape could hold the following formula:  
=GUARD(ThePage!PageWidth)  
If you've not come across the ShapeSheet before you might be interested in an intro post I blogged about a while ago:  
[Just for starters](http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2007/10/just-for-starte.html)  
Hope that helps.